# How do I strip malicious HTML (XXS etc.) from content submissions?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, web

I have a content submission form that contains multiple fields for input, all of which, when submitted, are entered directly into the database. When this content is requested, it is printed.

I have realized this is a security issue.

How can I strip malicious HTML (XSS) only, while still allowing formatting tags (`b`, `i` etc.)?

Comment: Assuming that you are actually using proper database access (**use placeholders!!!**, and the implementation isn't broken) and proper rendering (e.g. escaping for the output context) then ... nothing! Those are sort of BIG IFs for most [PHP] development though :-/ While I am not saying "don't sanitize input" (it should be filtered to the *accepted data-range*, as per business rules), I am pointing out that if you rely on sanitizing techniques to "make code safe" then there are other design issues that need to be addressed first (or concurrently). And please, *use a proven library*.

Comment: As far as "storing HTML and shoving it into a page later": Use caution -- if you do *explicitly accept tags* instead of *restrict tags* and *use a library to do so*. I would store/use a markup format that is guaranteed safe and dis-allow all direct HTML constructs (and *use a library to do so*). For instance, StackOverflow appears to be using some form of [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) with extensions. The library should also be aware of generating *valid* HTML markup. Unbalanced tags can really ruin a page rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst) is correct...you need to *explicitly allow certain tags*.  But the problem is that the input can be all over the place therefore you'll need to use a library like [HTML Tidy (link to Source Forge Project)](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to get it into a place where you can then [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) the cleaned document.

You should use `HTML Tidy` to clean your input and get it into a complaint state so you can then *explicitly allow certain tags*.  Everything else should be removed from your cleaned content before its permanently stored.  (NOTE: for performance reasons do not store BLOBs in your database, store them in your file system and link to them with a file path in a secure location - a location that is not in your web root).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First run `htmlspecialchars` on the input and then undo it for the allowed tags (for example, replace `&lt;b&gt;` with `<b>`).

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_stripslashes(), htmlspecialchars() and urldecode(), for integer values you can probably just int typecast.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly define which "innocent" html tags you are going to allow - like `<strong>` or `<em>`. Then run a regex to accept only those you want while rejecting all others.

Comment: You don't ever use regex for this, you sue an xml parser, otherwise your are setting yourself up for serious failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think encoding the input would help...

For PHP I believe it is:

```
htmlspecialchars
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this.

First off lets be clear: to do this in a secure manner, it cannot be done in javascript, only on the serverside - **using javascript to securely enforce input sanitation is doomed to fail**

1. Encode the chars that make up html when you output user generated data

When the user generated data is outputted on your webpage, change a few of the charachters to make it secure. Namely the characters `<`, `>` and `&` should be changed to `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` respectively.

This is the best way to do it, if the user should be allowed to edit the text, since you don't actually alter the text in storage, and you can let the user change the unmodified text via a `textarea`

1. Encode the chars that make up html when you store the user generated data

Do the same as above, but do it before you store the data in your db.

This has a performance upside, since you don't need to encode it every time you output it, but it will not let your users edit the unmodified text, which can be a serious downside, depending on what you are building

1. Strip the characters before output or storage

Strip the `<` and `>` characters before either output or storage - this is not a very good solution in my opinion, since it is an unnecessary altering of user input, but some people prefer it.